# When does sybase sql anywhere generate computed column values

Tags: sql, select, insert, calculated-columns, sqlanywhere

When does SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere genreated `Computed Column` values?

Does this happens during `wirint` or `select`ing data?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

While writing.
Try for yourself by creating a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a int, b int compute(a/0))
```

Then do an INSERT and a SELECT to see when the error occurs.